# How do you control how many chunks are built before it is sent?

Tags: java, grpc

I am using GRPC to chunk data so it sends smaller chunks.  For the most part it is okay, but I tried to do a `streamAll` of a table rather than getting a single entry and from the client side it does not appear to be getting any of the stream chunks of messages that I am sending via `onNext()` on the server.

Is there something I am missing or is there a relatively large sized buffer that I am not aware of and I'm just using up all my memory?

Comment: `onNext()` is asynchronous. It doesn't block. Are you casting the passed StreamObserver to ServerCallStreamObserver and setting an onReady handler? https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/ServerCallStreamObserver.html#setOnReadyHandler-java.lang.Runnable-

Answer (score 0):

My answer to your other question applies here as well. Try setting flow control using https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/netty/NettyServerBuilder.html#initialFlowControlWindow-int-